# arrangement of numbers so that a condition is satisfied...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can we arrange the numbers $1,2, \dots, 3n (n \geq 1)$, so that, at the positions that are multiple of $3$, there are only numbers that are multiple of $3$?

I thought that the answer is:
$$\binom{3n}{n} \cdot n! \cdot (2n)!$$

Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: I get  simply $n!(2n)!$.

Comment: Why?? are there $n$ positions that are multiple of $3$?

Comment: Yes there are, $3k$ for $k=1$ to $n$.

Comment: I haven't understood it...why are there $n$ multiples of $3$?

Comment: Take $n=5$. The positions that are multiples of $3$ are positions $3, 6, 9, 12, 15$.

Comment: A ok...I understand...thank you!!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the numbers from $1$ to $3n$, there are $n$ that are multiples of $3$, namely the numbers $3,6,9,\dots, 3n$. The count is easiest if we think of them as $3k$, where $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$, so through $n$ values.

Similarly, there are $n$ positions that are multiples of $3$.

Since there are $n$ numbers divisible by $3$, and $n$ positions divisible by $3$, we have $n!$ ways to arrange the $n$ multiples of $3$ in allowed positions. For each of these ways, we can arrange the $2n$ remaining numbers in the remaining positions in $(2n)!$ ways.

**Remark:** We can change the problem and make it a little harder by asking that multiples of $3$ all land in positions that are **not**  multiples of $3$. In that case, the *set* of positions occupied by multiples of $3$ can be chosen in $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways, and the rest goes as above.

Comment: I understand...thank you very much!!!

Comment: You are welcome. I think with a few more examples, you will have good control over the ideas.